# How to retrieve tr height when the browser zooming changes using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, tablerow

I am working on a website using `ASP.Net` and I need to retrieve a table row height using javascript or jquery when the browser zoom changes.
I tried to use `$("#idOfTableRow").height();` but it gives me a null value may be because the table exists in the default page and I am writing the jquery code in another page not related to default page.
Can someone tell me what should I do to retrieve the tr height?
Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe in js it will work in your default page.

```
 document.getElementById('yourtablerowid').clientHeight
```